# Terraform destroying RDS instance and retaining automated backups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, terraform

I have created and I have been managing a Postgresql RDS instance using Terraform.

Assuming I perform a `terraform destroy`, will this also delete the associated RDS snapshots that have been taken via the RDS schedule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When destroying an RDS database you have the [option to either create a long lived final snapshot or retain the automated backups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_DeleteInstance.html) which will be deleted as per the schedule they were set for:

> Instead of creating a snapshot, you can choose to enable Retain automated backups when you delete a DB instance. These backups are still subject to the retention period of the DB instance and age out the same way systems snapshots do.

Terraform supports keeping a final snapshot by setting the [`final_snapshot_identifier`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html#final_snapshot_identifier) and making sure that [`skip_final_snapshot`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html#skip_final_snapshot) is not set to `true`.

Unfortunately, Terraform doesn't currently support retaining the automated backups taken from scheduled snapshots but there is an [open feature request](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/6507) with a couple of half finished pull requests linked to it.

Answer (score 4):

Terraform added the option to keep the automated backups for an RDS with the [delete_automated_backups](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance#delete_automated_backups) flag. Just set this to false.